# Programming Assignment

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first time using this website to ask for help, but I was wondering why my code isn't running. I'm a first year student and am therefore thoroughly flustered! Any help would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance. And I apologize about the formatting (I had a hard time trying to fix it in the snippet editor on this site).

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset ="UTF-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>var firstPerson = prompt(""Enter the full name of the first person:")</script>
 <script>var secondPerson = prompt(""Enter the full name of the second person:")</script>
 <script>var thirdPerson = prompt(""Enter the full name of the third person:")</script>
 <script>var fourthPerson = prompt(""Enter the full name of the fourth person:")</script>
 <script>var fifthPerson = prompt(""Enter the full name of the fifth person:")</script>
 <script>alert("\"\\nThe \\nFirst\\n Person is ".concat("'", firstPerson, "'", "\\n\"\n\'\\nThe \\nSecond\\n Person is ",
    '"', secondPerson, '"', "\\n\'\n\"\\nThe \\nThird\\n Person is ", '"', thirdPerson, '"', "\\n\"\n\'\\nThe \\nFourth\\n Person is ", 
 "'", fourthPerson, "'", "\\n\'\n\"\\nThe \\nFifth\\n Person is \\", fifthPerson, "\\", "\\n\""))</script>
 <script>document.write("First Person: ".concat(firstPerson))</script>
 <script>document.write("First person (last name, first name): ".concat(firstPerson.substring(5,14), ", ", firstPerson.substring(0, 4)))</script>
 <script>document.write("Second Person: ".concat(secondPerson))</script>
 <script>document.write("Second person (last name, first name): ".concat(secondPerson.substring(6,10), ", ", secondPerson.substring(0, 5)))</script>
 <script>document.write("Third Person: ".concat(thirdPerson))</script>
 <script>document.write("Third person (last name, first name): ".concat(thirdPerson.substring(6,11), ", ", thirdPerson.substring(0, 5)))</script>
 <script>document.write("Fourth Person: ".concat(fourthPerson))</script>
 <script>document.write("Fourth person (last name, first name): ".concat(fourthPerson.substring(6,12), ", ", fourthPerson.substring(0, 5)))</script>
 <script>document.write("Fifth Person: ".concat(fifthPerson))</script>
 <script>document.write("Fifth person (last name, first name): ".concat(fifthPerson.substring(6,10), ", ", fifthPerson.substring(0, 5)))</script>
 <script>document.write("All of the first names are: ".concat(firstPerson.substring(0,4), ", ", secondPerson.substring(0,5), ", ", thirdPerson.substring(0,5),
    ", ", fourthPerson.substring(0,5), ", ", fifthPerson.substring(0,5)))</script>
 <script>document.write("All of the last names are: ".concat(firstPerson.substring(5,14), ", ", secondPerson.substring(6,10), ", ", thirdPerson.substring(6,11), 
 ", ", fourthPerson.substring(6,12), ", ", fifthPerson.substring(6,10)))</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is there in the body? All i am seeing is Script

Comment: Firstly, you do not need to put every line of code in a `script` tag, try to include `type='text/javascript'` in your script tag, your *one* script tag. I'll see what I can do with your code.

Comment: Press F12, click console, clear out the results and run your snippet again.  Those errors will be a good place to start.

Comment: Yes, I'm going to clean it up by taking out all those script tags (I didn't know  about that!), thank you. Also that's a good tip about seeing the errors, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I noticed were your double-quotes, you probably use a code editor and thus when you type one double-quote, the next appears automatically. You didn't notice and this closed off your call.

I fixed this here.

```
 var firstPerson = prompt("Enter the full name of the first person:")
 var secondPerson = prompt("Enter the full name of the second person:")
 var thirdPerson = prompt("Enter the full name of the third person:")
 var fourthPerson = prompt("Enter the full name of the fourth person:")
 var fifthPerson = prompt("Enter the full name of the fifth person:")
```

Also, you do not need to put each line of code in `script` tags,

Try to do something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    // Code here...

</script>
```

What you want seems to work except your formatted results are quite insane and I suggest you clean them up a bit, hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't even notice the double quotes like you said because I have been using Notepad++ and haven't gotten used to it quite yet. We're learning about escape sequences right now and the assignment was to display our results with "//n" nested inside at certain spots so I can see why the results might seem crazy. I'm glad I don't need to use script tags all the time! That's super helpful. Thanks again and thank you for your patience.

Comment: It's no problem at all! Glad I was of use :)